# Where to find the decisions of the Supreme Court of India?

Tags: india, court-records

I've tried to look up the full decision on the plea that was looking to ban the BBC in relation to *India: The Modi Question* documentary ban by the Indian Government

This [Article](https://www.telegraphindia.com/india/supreme-court-throws-out-plea-to-ban-bbc/cid/1915747) mentions that the Supreme Court of India dismissed the PIL to ban the BBC, but I can't find the decision.

Searching the [Judgment directory](https://main.sci.gov.in/judgments) for either BBC or reading either justice's that the article said were involved docket but didn't give any result.

Getting the whole [Case Status](https://main.sci.gov.in/case-status) list doesn't help either

Is there a specific way to access such decisions? Because, they don't seem to appear on the main SCI site

Answer (score 1):

In addition to judgments, you should have looked at "[Daily Orders](https://main.sci.gov.in/daily-order)". The decision is uploaded here, amongst other situations, particularly if the case is devoid of merits and the SCI has not given a judgment. The decision on the BBC ban case was also uploaded here.

Also, since your question was general, I additionally refer you to [e-SCR](https://districts.ecourts.gov.in/e-scr), which allows for keyword search of reportable judgments and orders.

All of this is in addition to the free databases 'IndianKanoon' and 'LII of India' which upload judgments from various courts and tribunals in India.